# EDM song, video with 2 teddy bears, lyrics: "we were gold"

Tags: lyrics

I've been looking for an EDM (electronic dance music) song

the video of this song has two teddy bears in it 
and the lyrics are

> we were gold and we were......

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxm1mb8JTvw

John Dahlbäck feat. Urban Cone & Lucas Nord - We Were Gods (Official Video)